# How to do complement for one bit in verilog

Tags: verilog, xilinx, complement

I want to ask about switching one bit for example x[3] in bit vector x[0:3] to one if it's zero or to zero if it's one in verilog.So if x=0101 it will become x=0100 .I have tried concatination with not but it's error in verilog .Can you help me to do that?
My code is here :http://www.edaplayground.com/x/JAc
where x:input and y:x after mutate one bit

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To alter one bit as part of a bus:

```
module bit_mangle(
  input  [3:0] x,
  output [3:0] y
);

  always @* begin
    y = {x[3:1], ~x[0]} ;
  end

endmodule
```

I have updated a copy of your code on EDA playground, and fixed a few issues in the testharness.
[Working simulation on EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/KPn).

It is more common to define buses from [SIZE-1:0]. Your old Mutation code was trying to drive the input in two places rather than letting the level above drive the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
always_comb begin
   x    = 4'b0101 ; 
   x[3] = ~x[3] ; //overwrite x[3] with its complement
end
```

or

```
always_comb begin
   x    = 4'b0101 ; 
   x[3] = x[3] ^ 1'b1 ; //XOR x[3] with 1
end
```

Comment: Thank you .. but there is still many errors.This my code can you help me please?
where x:input and y:x after mutate 1 bit.
module Mutation(x,y);

  input [0:3] x=0000;
 output [0:3] y;
 reg [0:3] y;
 always @(x) begin
   x    = 4'b0101 ; 
   x[3] = ~x[3] ; //overwrite x[3] with its complement
 y={x[0:3]};

  end
 
endmodule
//also and this is the test bench 
module TBMutation;
parameter s=4;
 reg [0:s-1] x;
 wire [0:s-1] y;
 Mutation m (.x(x),.y(y),);
 initial begin
  // Initialize Input
  x = 2;
  // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
  #100;
     end
    endmodule

Comment: This is the error :Line 30: Procedural assignment to a non-register x is not permitted, left-hand side should be reg/integer/time/genvar

line 30 is at :x[3] = ~x[3] ;

Comment: It's good practice to write your code in a clean way -rather than in comments - so others can read it easily. You can also write it here http://www.edaplayground.com/ and post a link on this website. Also, you may want to review this page before posting questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Assignments should either be in `always` blocks or with `assign` keyword.

Comment: but in my code assignments are inside always ,can you write the code after modification to understand what you mean?

Comment: No, line 9 is outside.

Comment: I solve it this is the true one :)
always @(x) begin
        y    = {x[0],x[1],x[2],~x[3]};
  end
Thank you Ari